# Block a node with several executors from accepting more jobs until a given job is completed

Tags: selenium, amazon-ec2, jenkins

I am running a Selenium test suite on ec2 windows instances. These instances should be restarted once every few days as maintenance to free up memory etc.

The problem I have is when I send the restart-command to the slave from Jenkins, I can´t be certain that the slave have no running jobs at that time, since the slave run several executors.

Is there a way to tell a node that, as soon as job X is triggered, drop the amount of executors to 0? If not, is there a way to gracefully put a slave offline (i.e: "complete all jobs in que but don´t accept any new jobs")?

Comment: You have more than one question it seems, 1. how do you schedule the restart seamlessly, 2. how do you shutdown a slave. A possibility for #1 would be to create a new job that runs periodically every couple of days that takes up N executors where N is the maximum number of executors and runs on a particular node you specify. You can then set up a build matrix that covers all of the nodes. As far as #2 how to actually restart the node, depending on the OS you would then just run a reboot command.

Comment: one way could be to run a daemon on the slave that reports to a server whether or not it is still running a job

Answer (score -1):

> `(jenkins_url)/safeRestart` - Allows all running jobs to complete. New
>   jobs will remain in the queue to run after the restart is complete.